# Piwik move views to another site id

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, matomo

I need to move some page views from one site to another because an page generation fault generated my website with an incorrect site_id.

Can anyone here tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use server access logs. You can import the data using [--replay-tracking](http://piwik.org/faq/log-analytics-tool/#faq_19221) option. Make sure that you have proper site ID in logs, you can use sed to replace incorrect idsite with the one you would like to use.

Comment: That's no option for me because of custom variables and events.
But the sites have got different domains.
Maybe it's possible to modify the database?

Comment: Custom variables and events can be replayed from tracker access logs (requests to piwik.php resource).

Comment: By the way ... I'm unable to access the server logs.

Comment: To clearify, do you mean the logs of the server piwik is running on? These can be accessed by me, but not the logs of the site itself.

Comment: Logs on Piwik server (requests to /piwik.php).